# How to drop columns from data frame with less than 2 unique levels in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with numeric and categorical variables with ~200,000 rows, but many variables are constants(both numeric and cat). I am trying to create a new dataset where the `length(unique(data.frame$factor))<=1` variables are dropped.

Example data set and attempts so far:

```
Temp=c(26:30)
Feels=c("cold","cold","cold","hot","hot")
Time=c("night","night","night","night","night")
Year=c(2015,2015,2015,2015,2015)
DF=data.frame(Temp,Feels,Time,Year)
```

I would think a loop would work, but something isn't working in my 2 below attempts. I've tried:

```
for (i in unique(colnames(DF))){
  Reduced_DF <- DF[,(length(unique(DF$i)))>1]
}
```

But I really need a vector of the colnames where length(unique(DF$columns))>1, so I tried the below instead, to no avail.

```
for (i in unique(DF)){
  if (length(unique(DF$i)) >1)
  {keepvars <- c(DF$i)}
  Reduced_DF <- DF[keepvars]
}
```

Does anyone out there have experience with this type of subsetting/dropping of columns with less than a certain level count?

Comment: Also, a few reasons why your for loops aren't working: 1) You're creating a new variable `Reduced_DF` in each iteration instead of changing the original, meaning it forgets after each loop, 2) You can't access a column with `DF$i`, you would need `DF[[i]]`, 3) the expression `DF[,(length(unique(DF$i)))>1]` is trying to subset from all columns, not deciding whether to keep `i`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find out how many unique values are in each column with:

```
sapply(DF, function(col) length(unique(col)))
#  Temp Feels  Time  Year 
#  5     2     1     1
```

You can use this to subset the columns:

```
DF[, sapply(DF, function(col) length(unique(col))) > 1]
#   Temp Feels
# 1   26  cold
# 2   27  cold
# 3   28  cold
# 4   29   hot
# 5   30   hot
```

Comment: Yep, and if you need the names for some other explicit purpose, something like: `names(DF)[sapply(DF, function(x) length(unique(x))>1 )]` will do it.

Comment: Or `DF[sapply(DF, function(x) !is.factor(x) | nlevels(x) > 1)]` if you wanna introduce `nlevels` - the number of levels of a factor.

Comment: Or `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, DF)` for a nicer code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. These all work and provide other suggestions for future usage. I quick question for @DavidRobinson, I've noticed that while it makes sense to be explicit in applying the function over all rows and subsetting on columns using `[, sapply()]`, it also works without the `,`. Is this just because `length()` is a column/factor function so by default it applies over all rows? Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @surfhoya Thanks. Not quite: it's because you can access columns of a data frame either with `DF[, condition]` or `DF[condition]`, because a data frame is a special case of a list. For example, try `mtcars[, 1:5]`, then `mtcars[1:5]` (same result).

Answer (score 6):

Another way with `data.table`

```
#Convert object to data.table object
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

#Drop columns
todrop <- names(DF)[which(sapply(DF,uniqueN)<2)]
DF[, (todrop) := NULL]
```

One advantage to this method is that it does not make a copy (which might be useful when you have as many columns as you have).

If you are using `data.table 1.9.4`, you would change to the following:

```
#Drop columns
todrop <- names(DF)[which(sapply(DF,function(x) length(unique(x)<2))]
DF[, (todrop) := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike.Gahan for your approach using `data.table`. I'm interested in learning more about this package and functionality, but on my end, the code errored out becaue `uniqueN` wasn't found. Am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake...`uniqueN` is implemented on data.table 1.9.5, and the latest CRAN release is 1.9.4. If you want to use this method, you could either download 1.9.5 `library(devtools); install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`, or you could replace `uniqueN` with `length(unqieu(x))`

Answer (score 0):

I've also another possible solution for dropping the columns with categorical value with 2 lines of code, defining a list with columns of categorical values (1st line) and dropping them with the second line. df is our dataframe

df with categorical column:

[image: df with categorical column]

```
 list=pd.DataFrame(df.categorical).columns
 df= df.drop(list,axis=1)
```

df after running the code:

[image: df after running the code]

Comment: The question is about R not Python :) it is specified clearly in the title.

Comment: You are right, I put the comment in wrong window (I thought it was Python and not R). Do you know if is it possible to delete it? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it might depend on your badges/points but I think it should be possible to delete your answer.